# How to get a part of the patch where script located?

Tags: bash, svn

I would like to automatically copy the committed files from svn repository to a certain folder with the same name.

For example, I have svn repository `/svn/project1` and after commit it should put all files to `/www/project1`.

I have a simple post-commit hook script but can't understand how to get a part of necessary directory (`project1`):

```
#!/bin/sh
PROJECTNAME=                    # how get it?
rm -rf /www/$PROJECTNAME
mkdir /www/$PROJECTNAME
/usr/bin/svn export --force file:///svn/$PROJECTNAME/trunk /www/$PROJECTNAME
```

Comment: Part of the directory *name* is more precise. It sounded at first like you wanted part of the *contents* of the directory.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed. Hope it is now more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Bash parameter expansion:

```
PROJECTNAME=${PWD##*/}
```

To get the parent directory requires two steps:

```
PROJECTNAME=${PWD%/*}
PROJECTNAME=${PROJECTNAME##*/}
```

Comment: I think the trouble is to get the specific _child_ directory. :/

Comment: @vlad: does this exactly do what you need? if so, please [mark it accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so everyone knows it's done... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
echo $PWD | awk -vFS=/ '{printf "%s",$NF}'
```

For all the test cases I came up with, it prints *something* -- with the exception of the `/` directory. So this won't work for `/`. (But that's not exactly something you want to do anyway.)

If this appears to work for you, then try this in your script:

```
PROJECTNAME=$(echo $PWD | awk -vFS=/ '{printf "%s",$NF}')
```

Comment: `PROJECTNAME=$(echo "${PWD##*/}")` is all you need.

Comment: @Dennis: Ha! I tried those variable modifiers first but didn't find the one I was after. Nice. Please add that as an answer, you more than deserve the points for it. :)

Comment: Done. I goofed in my comment, though. You don't need the command substitution and the `echo` when you use the parameter expansion.

Comment: @sarnold, @Dennis Williamson as I understand it got a current directory. But the hooks are located on one directory above, in my example the full path to script: /svn/project1/hooks/post-commit.sh. So, the result would be `hooks`

Comment: @vlad: Ah, that's a serious wrinkle in the ointment (to mix metaphors..) ... how does the hook know which files are modified?

Comment: @sarnold Hook-script don't know it. It just remove current content (if it exist) and put the new content when commit happened.